# Customising the floating button to show in one tab

Tags: tabs, codenameone

I would like to show my floating button in one Tab, how can I overcome that?
[image: Image of the second tab]
[image: floating button in the first tab]

Comment: You can use the method `bindFabToContainer` of the class `FloatingActionButton` to bind the FAB to the Container that you want, like the container included in a tab.

Answer (score 1):

As @francesco-galgani wrote this is indeed the case. Instead of doing:

```
tabs.add("Tab Name", myContainer);
```

Do:

```
Container withFab = FloatingActionButton.bindFabToContainer(myContainer);
tabs.add("Tab Name", withFab);
```

Notice we now need to add the `withFab` container.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shai Almong and @francesco-galgani

This will help one to sit the fab in the right position (Bottom right) in a specific tab

And give it a color you want using Styles

```
 Container tabContainer = BorderLayout.center(new Label("tab content goes here");

 FloatingActionButton myfab = FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD);
    myfab.getStyle().setBgColor(ColorUtil.rgb(25, 118, 210));
    Container withFab = BorderLayout.center(myfab.bindFabToContainer(tabContainer, Component.RIGHT, Component.BOTTOM));

    UserRolesTabs.addTab("Tab Name", withFab);
```